# Django: How to set the correct the location for MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am just starting to use MySQL as the database for my project. Previously I had been using SQLite.

I am wondering how to specify the location for the MySQL database the same way I was able to for SQLite. Currently it saves automatically to `/usr/local/mysql/data` by default. But I believe this will cause issues when I try to upload it to my production envroment.

**My old SQLite settings**

```
DATABASES = {
     'default': {
         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
         'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'database/db.sqlite3'),
     }
}
```

This saved the database into a database folder in my project which I was able to upload and chown both to www-data. This seems like a simple solution which I would like to replicate with MySQL

**My new MySQL settings**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': { 
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        #'NAME': 'django_db',   
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'database/django_db'),                                       
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'myPassword',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306', 
    }
}
```

However when I try to `syncdb` with this I get the below error

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1059, "Identifier name
>   '/users/user/workspace/bias_experiment/src/database/django_db'
>   is too long") (bias_experiment)localhost:src user$

I also tried to create the database within my project with

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE /Users/user/workspace/bias_experiment/src/database/django_db;
```

But this gave me the error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '/Users/brendan/Dropbox/workspace/bias_experiment/src/database/django_db' at line 1
mysql>
```

So can I create the DB with in my project and link to it in the same way as I did previously with SQLite? And If not what is the correct way/location to upload it to and link to it?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL is not a file-based database: you don't give it a file path. In fact the settings file itself is quite clear about what you need to put in the NAME attribute, ie (not surprisingly) the name of the database itself. This is the same as you need for CREATE DATABASE, but again you don't give that a path: just a name.

Comment: I suppose what I don't understand then is how to deploy the MySQL DB to the server? If it is not in my project directory (as SQLite was), is there a command similar to collectstatic or something or is the syncdb doing this and I can just forget about it and upload as normal?

Comment: @Deepend It's vary host to host, In my case i hosted my project to heroku there i didn't create database, heroku create db & take care for everything

Comment: You don't "deploy" a database to the server: as I say, it's not a file you can just copy around. syncdb - or, preferably, migrations - will create the table structure, and you can also use data migrations to add any initial data.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access mysql files directly. You must create a database (give it a name, not a path) and access it.

```
SQL> CREATE DATABASE django_db
```